# replace fraction with decimal in Excel using vbscript

Tags: excel, replace, vbscript, find, contains

As part of a larger script, I am trying to replace fraction values with decimal values in excel using vbscript. I can always count on the values to have a specific column and a specific format.

Excel example expected input column B:

```
51-7/16
1-1/2
2
15-7/8
```

Excel example desired output column B:

```
51.4375
1.5
2
15.875
```

I know it will always be to a 1/16th. So my idea was to go through the list looking for each possible fraction, find a cell that contains that fraction, and replace it with the corresponding decimal.

Questions: How do I tell the script to find a cell that contains a value and how do I replace that fraction with the decimal?

closest example [Search and Replace a number of characters in Excel using VBscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39955339/search-and-replace-a-number-of-characters-in-excel-using-vbscript)

Attempt:

```
Dim FMember (14)
FMember(0) = "-1/16"
FMember(1) = "-1/8"
FMember(2) = "-3/16"
FMember(3) = "-1/4"
FMember(4) = "-5/16"
FMember(5) = "-3/8"
FMember(6) = "-7/16"
FMember(7) = "-1/2"
FMember(8) = "-9/16"
FMember(9) = "-5/8"
FMember(10) = "-11/16"
FMember(11) = "-3/4"
FMember(12) = "-13/16"
FMember(13) = "-7/8"
FMember(14) = "-15/16"

Dim DMember(14)
DMember(0) = ".0625"
DMember(1) = ".125"
DMember(2) = ".1875"
DMember(3) = ".25"
DMember(4) = ".3125"
DMember(5) = ".375"
DMember(6) = ".4375"
DMember(7) = ".5"
DMember(8) = ".5625"
DMember(9) = ".625"
DMember(10) = ".6875"
DMember(11) = ".75"
DMember(12) = ".8125"
DMember(13) = ".875"
DMember(14) = ".9375"
Dim endRow2
endRow2 = objSheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For lngPosition = LBound(FMember) To UBound(FMember)
      For r = 1 To endRow2
          If objSheet2.Cells(r, objSheet2.Columns("B").Column).Value = FMember(lngPosition) Then
              objSheet2.replace
          End If
      Next
Next
```

Comment: Split on the `-` then if the second part exists then use application.evaluate() to get the decimal and add the two together.

Answer (score 1):

Use split()

```
Function fract(str As String) As Double
Dim strArr() As String
If InStr(str, "-") Then
    strArr = Split(str, "-")
    fract = strArr(0) + Application.Evaluate(strArr(1))
Else
    fract = Application.Evaluate(str)
End If
End Function
```

Then you can use it as a worksheet function:

```
=fract(A1)
```

[image]

Comment: i received an error expected ')' on first line before As String.

Comment: Not sure why, do you have `Dim strArr() As String`?

Comment: yes, I do. I'm curious more about how to incorporate this into the larger program. Do I need to use a for loop in order to apply this to the B column for all used cells?

Comment: Just call it from inside a loop passing the range value into:`Range("A1") = fract(Range("A1").Value)`